# Unable to setup COM port, check it is correct

Tags: php

I am sending sms using Nokia usb Device and PHP script but getting error 
many answer are there on stack but no answer has solution of this problem

```
 Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: Unable to setup COM port, check it is correct in C:\xampp\htdocs\sms-prac\send-sms.php:103
    Stack trace:
    #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\sms-prac\send-sms.php(36): gsm_send_sms->init()
    #1 {main}
      thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\sms-prac\send-sms.php on line 103
```

**My gsm_send_sms  Class Code**

```
    //Send SMS via serial SMS modem
    class gsm_send_sms {

        public $port = 'COM1';
        public $baud = 115200;

        public $debug = false;

        private $fp;
        private $buffer;

        //Setup COM port
        public function init() {

            $this->debugmsg("Setting up port: \"{$this->port} @ \"{$this->baud}\" baud");

            exec("MODE {$this->port}: BAUD={$this->baud} PARITY=N DATA=8 STOP=1", $output, $retval);

            if ($retval != 0) {
                throw new Exception('Unable to setup COM port, check it is correct');
            }

            $this->debugmsg(implode("\n", $output));

            $this->debugmsg("Opening port");

            //Open COM port
            $this->fp = fopen($this->port . ':', 'r+');

            //Check port opened
            if (!$this->fp) {
                throw new Exception("Unable to open port \"{$this->port}\"");
            }

            $this->debugmsg("Port opened");
            $this->debugmsg("Checking for responce from modem");

            //Check modem connected
            fputs($this->fp, "AT\r");

            //Wait for ok
            $status = $this->wait_reply("OK\r\n", 5);

            if (!$status) {
                throw new Exception('Did not receive responce from modem');
            }

            $this->debugmsg('Modem connected');

            //Set modem to SMS text mode
            $this->debugmsg('Setting text mode');
            fputs($this->fp, "AT+CMGF=1\r");

            $status = $this->wait_reply("OK\r\n", 5);

            if (!$status) {
                throw new Exception('Unable to set text mode');
            }

            $this->debugmsg('Text mode set');

        }

        //Wait for reply from modem
        private function wait_reply($expected_result, $timeout) {

            $this->debugmsg("Waiting {$timeout} seconds for expected result");

            //Clear buffer
            $this->buffer = '';

            //Set timeout
            $timeoutat = time() + $timeout;

            //Loop until timeout reached (or expected result found)
            do {

                $this->debugmsg('Now: ' . time() . ", Timeout at: {$timeoutat}");

                $buffer = fread($this->fp, 1024);
                $this->buffer .= $buffer;

                usleep(200000);//0.2 sec

                $this->debugmsg("Received: {$buffer}");

                //Check if received expected responce
                if (preg_match('/'.preg_quote($expected_result, '/').'$/', $this->buffer)) {
                    $this->debugmsg('Found match');
                    return true;
                    //break;
                } else if (preg_match('/\+CMS ERROR\:\ \d{1,3}\r\n$/', $this->buffer)) {
                    return false;
                }

            } while ($timeoutat > time());

            $this->debugmsg('Timed out');

            return false;

        }

        //Print debug messages
        private function debugmsg($message) {

            if ($this->debug == true) {
                $message = preg_replace("%[^\040-\176\n\t]%", '', $message);
                echo $message . "\n";
            }

        }

        //Close port
        public function close() {

            $this->debugmsg('Closing port');

            fclose($this->fp);

        }

        //Send message
        public function send($tel, $message) {

            //Filter tel
            $tel = preg_replace("%[^0-9\+]%", '', $tel);

            //Filter message text
            $message = preg_replace("%[^\040-\176\r\n\t]%", '', $message);

            $this->debugmsg("Sending message \"{$message}\" to \"{$tel}\"");

            //Start sending of message
            fputs($this->fp, "AT+CMGS=\"{$tel}\"\r");

            //Wait for confirmation
            $status = $this->wait_reply("\r\n> ", 5);

            if (!$status) {
                //throw new Exception('Did not receive confirmation from modem');
                $this->debugmsg('Did not receive confirmation from modem');
                return false;
            }

            //Send message text
            fputs($this->fp, $message);

            //Send message finished indicator
            fputs($this->fp, chr(26));

            //Wait for confirmation
            $status = $this->wait_reply("OK\r\n", 180);

            if (!$status) {
                //throw new Exception('Did not receive confirmation of messgage sent');
                $this->debugmsg('Did not receive confirmation of messgage sent');
                return false;
            }

            $this->debugmsg("Message sent");

            return true;

        }

    }
```

**My PHP Code which i am using to send SMS**

```
 <?php

    //SMS via GSM Modem - A PHP class to send SMS messages via a GSM modem attached to the computers serial port.

    //Windows only (tested on XP with PHP 5.2.6)
    //Tested with the EZ863 (Telit GE863) GSM modem
    //Requires that PHP has permission to access "COM" system device, and system "mode" command
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    //Example




    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "MembersManagmentSystem";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT Member.memberId, Member.memberContactMobileNumber, SMSRecipient.smsRecipientReceiverId, SMSRecipient.smsInfoId, SMSInfo.smsInfoText, SMSInfo.`smsInfoSaveDateTime` FROM Member, SMSRecipient,SMSInfo WHERE SMSRecipient.`smsRecipientReceiverId` = Member.`memberId` AND SMSRecipient.`smsInfoId`= SMSInfo.`smsInfoId` AND  SMSRecipient.smsRecipientSentDateTime IS NULL AND Member.`memberContactMobileNumber` IS NOT NULL AND SMSInfo.`smsInfoSaveDateTime` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
        echo "<pre>";

    $gsm_send_sms = new gsm_send_sms();
    $gsm_send_sms->debug = false;
    $gsm_send_sms->port = 'COM3';
    $gsm_send_sms->baud = 115200;
    $gsm_send_sms->init();



    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        print_r($row);

            $status = $gsm_send_sms->send($row['memberContactMobileNumber'], $row['smsInfoText']);


            if ($status) {

                $sql = "UPDATE SMSRecipient SET smsRecipientSentDateTime = now() WHERE smsInfoId = ".$row['smsInfoId']." and smsRecipientReceiverId = ".$row['memberId'];

                if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                   echo "Message sent\n";
                }

            } else {
                echo "Message not sent\n";
            }


        }



        //exit();
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }







    $gsm_send_sms->close();




    $conn->close();


    ?>
```

on change $gsm_send_sms->debug = false; to true, get

```
    Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => Status for device COM3:
    [2] => -----------------------
    [3] =>     Baud:            115200
    [4] =>     Parity:          None
    [5] =>     Data Bits:       8
    [6] =>     Stop Bits:       1
    [7] =>     Timeout:         OFF
    [8] =>     XON/XOFF:        OFF
    [9] =>     CTS handshaking: OFF
    [10] =>     DSR handshaking: OFF
    [11] =>     DSR sensitivity: OFF
    [12] =>     DTR circuit:     ON
    [13] =>     RTS circuit:     ON
    [14] => 
)
```

After Debug above Code I found that when i first time connect my device and run it php executing this line as like as infinity loop and before this line all debugmsg and other code running fine please help me

```
$buffer = fread($this->fp, 8192);
```

Comment: First, have you tried anything else than `COM3`? Second, what if you change `$gsm_send_sms->debug = false;` to `true`, do you get any more information? Which line is line 103 in the send_sms.php-file?

Comment: get output  Array
(
    [0] => Device COM3 is not currently available.
)

Comment: on change $gsm_send_sms->debug = false; to true,

Comment: Well, then it's not available. Either because it's the wrong port, or because PHP can't access it. Figure that out, or pick another COM-port, and it will probably work.

Comment: how can i pick the right port name please help me

Comment: Depending on your devices. Have you got a SMS serial modem? Or are you trying to send magical SMS through the smoke signals?

Comment: Your own code said on the comments `//Requires that PHP has permission to access "COM" system device, and system "mode" command`. I don't have anything to say.

Comment: i have sms modem so what i can do to get com port number

Comment: please just tell me what i am doing wrong where i need to do what